# Visual Studio Git Connection not correct for solution opened

Tags: git, visual-studio

**Step 1**

In Visual Studio 2015, The Team Explorer. I use Manage Connections to find the project i want to work with

Clone the project to get a copy of the files on my local machine

Close project 1

**Step 2**

Open up a second project to get a copy of the files on my local machine

Close Project 2

**Step 3**

Open up the solution for Project 1

I got to Team Explorer and under connections its looking at the connection for project 2

**Shouldnt it be set to look at the connection for Project 1?**